# Have there been any CSS changes in the last week?

Tags: bug, css

There used to be a differentation between visited and not visited links in the main EL&U site (Not the EL&U Meta site) Hot Network Questions column, today all the links are the same color (#333333).
The unvisited link used to be #ae3737.

[image: How the page looks currently]
How the page looks currently

I have tried both chrome & firefox (latest versions), also a complete page refresh (Ctrl + F5)

Is this an intentional change or an error?

Comment: That's how I see it too. Isn't that the default?

Comment: It seems the links to visited pages appear darker. Have you checked on SE Meta if anyone else has noticed this effect?

Comment: I tell you what *is* weird. I can't edit comments. When I open the window, instead of seeing my original comment, I just see the following **[object Object]**

Comment: @Mari-LouA css for visited links in SE sites is defined per site, as stated the unvisited link used to be #ae3737, which gave a good contrast to a visited link which I presume to be #333333. Now there is no contrast so unvisited links do not standout like they used to.

Comment: @Mari-LouA could be a js issue?

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. There used to be a greater contrast, I think you're right. But I don't really visit many HNQ links, maybe 2 or 3and sometimes never.

Comment: @Andrew Leach, as I'm not the only one having issues can you flag this up to SE devs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the colors for the HNQ have changed. But visited and unvisited links are different colors for me on main, so I need to ask: Have you clicked any of those links?

I checked the Wayback Machine for [August 16](https://web.archive.org/web/20180816094926/https://english.stackexchange.com/questions) on the main site and it shows this:

[image]

This isn't a particular surprise, since [it was announced ages ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309349/323179) that there would be changes to themes (among other things) across the network.

Currently (on the main site) I see this unvisited links in the HNQ as #333 (which is [the same as #333333](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3108860/6083675)) and visited links as #555 (again, aka #555555), same as [MetaEd](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11622/191178). These colors are the same colors that are used for question titles (e.g. on the main page):

[image]

(In case you don't have superhuman vision, the top one was visited.)

---

On Meta, I see both visited and unvisited HNQ links as #0C0D0E. (Actually, like main, titles links are also this color):

[image]

I think the HNQ links might be the same color on all metas, actually.

This really needs to be changed.

---

While I'm mentioning changes in link colors, I'll also state that I just noticed (on both meta and main) that the preview (e.g. of an answer you're composing) now shows a difference between visited and unvisited links like so:

[image]

(This is probably a good change.)

Comment: Thank you, I had not thought of  Wayback Machine.

Comment: The question now is how do we get greater differentation between the visited and unvisited link colours?

Comment: I'm still seeing #333333 for visited and unvisited

Comment: @Christopher It's a bit hard to know why without more details. Is your browser actually recording what URLs you've visited? (If you're in incognito, the answer is probably no, and you won't see a change for any link you visit.) If that's not what it is, and you know how to access the Developer Console, do you see the same CSS that MetaEd has in his answer?

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware of a recent change. My browser presents two colors for links in that sidebox. Visited links are #555. Unvisited links are #333. They are hard to differentiate visually. Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.question-hyperlink, .answer-hyperlink {
    color: #333;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

.question-hyperlink:visited, .answer-hyperlink:visited {
    color: #555;
}
```